# How do I get my faucet handle off?

Tags: leak, faucet, sink

I've been trying to get to the cartridge in my bathroom sink faucet handle.  I took off the top part, but in order to get the cartridge out it looks like I have to take off the bottom part as well.  I've tried prying it and turning it, but I'm not sure how it's supposed to come off.  I don't know the manufacturer of the faucet either.

I put WD-40 to help loosen the bottom edge but it doesn't seem to want to budge and I don't want to scratch it up.  Any suggestions?  Also, do I need to replace cartridges in both handles to stop a leak?  I'm new at this house fixing stuff.

[image: My Faucet]

Comment: Is there a setscrew somewhere (may have to turn the handle to access the hole)?

Comment: I agree with Tester101 look for a set screw. Do you have to change both ?  If you can figure out if it is hot or cold and get lucky you may be able to get by with just 1. Did you turn the water off and open the valve prior to trying to unscrew, sometimes water pressure makes things hard to unscrew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the piece of bell shaped trim surrounding the cartridge. There is very likely a large nut under there. To avoid scratching i usually wrap the lowest part of this trim with 3-4 winds of masking tape, then undo with water pump pliers. These spread the load nicely. You maybe lucky and get the leaky cartridge first, if not at least you know how to do it,so the next one will be easier.